# Express.js unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am getting some unexpected behaviour in my app.
My app.js code look like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.xml({
    xmlParseOptions: {
        normalize: true,
        normalizeTags: false,
        explicitArray: true
    }
}));

//app.use(bodyParser.raw({ inflate: true, limit: '5000kb', type: 'text' }));



app.get(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/version', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile('version.json', {root: path.join('./files')});
});


app.use(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/accounts', accountsRouter);
app.use(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/consents', consentsRouter,
    function (request,response) {
        console.log("hi");
    });

app.use(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/funds-confirmations', fundsConfirmationRouter);

app.use(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/periodic-payments', paymentsRouter);
app.use(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/payments', paymentsRouter);
app.use(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/bulk-payments', paymentsRouter);

app.use(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/redirect', redirectRouter);

app.use(constants.APP_NAME_URL + constants.VERSION_URL + '/e2e-status', e2eRouter);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    var businessErrorMessage = err.errorMessage ? err.errorMessage : constants.ERROR_MESSAGE_UNEXPECTED_ERROR;
    var businessErrorCode = err.errorCode ? err.errorCode : constants.ERROR_CODE_UNEXPECTED_ERROR;
    var errorResponse = errorHandler.errorResponse(constants.ERROR_CATEGORY_ERROR,
        businessErrorCode,
        businessErrorMessage);
    debug(err.stack);
    responseBuilder.respond(req, res, errorResponse, 400, constants.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON);
});
```

When I send a request to the /consents endpoint with a JSON-body and with application/xml as content type in the header, it directly goes to the business error middleware and not to the consents router when I debug the app.

What I mean is a request like this:

```
POST /sandbox/v1/consents HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:33589
X-Request-ID: 9a906a04-0610-4e94-9f6b-1bcf25f05214
Content-Type: application/xml
TPP-Redirect-Preferred: false
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:33589
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 192
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{
 "access": {
  "availableAccountsWithBalance": "allAccounts"
 },
 "recurringIndicator": true,
 "validUntil": "2021-09-08",
 "frequencyPerDay": 4,
 "combinedServiceIndicator": false
}
```

If I send this request via Postman i get the business error middleware instead of the consents router. If I change the content type to application/json or something nonsense like "hi", I get to the consents router, how can I explain this behaviour?

Comment: Please add the code for the `consentsRouter` and what are the values of `constants.APP_NAME_URL` `constants.VERSION_URL`?

Comment: Where are you getting `bodyParser.xml()` from?  That is not part of the standard bodyparer module.  Please include a link to the module you are getting that from.  It seems likely you aren't using it correctly.

Comment: @jfriend00 this one  https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-xml

Comment: @jfriend00 I dont think it has to do something with my constants, because if I use application/json as content type, everything works as it is supposed to be

Comment: So, you are setting `Content-Type: application/xml`, but your content is not XML.  The content looks like JSON.  That would be a major problem.  That would also be why it works when you set `Content-Type: application/json`.  So, why don't you just use the JSON content type?

Comment: I want to give a error message if someone does it, but I can not get into the part where I could send an error message

Comment: So, the whole question here is how to provide an error message if someone gives you `Content-Type: application/xml`?

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is to send an error if someone sends you a post with `Content-Type: application/xml`, then you can do that with some simple middleware like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.get('Content-Type') === "application/xml") {
        res.status(415).send("Unsupported content-type");
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

And, put this before any of your request handlers so it gets first crack at the request.  If you want this to only be in effect for POST requests, then you can also check if `req.method === "POST"`.

And, remove the middleware for that content type here:

```
app.use(bodyParser.xml({...}));
```

If you're not going to be using that content-type, then you don't need to be parsing it.

Comment: Okay I forgot tomention, I have some endpints where I use XML, so I can not do it like this I guess

Comment: @YasinEraslan - Well, you're not really disclosing the entire problem here.  You can order the routes so that the ones that use application/xml are BEFORE this middleware and the ones that you want to prohibit it from are AFTER this middleware.  Or, you can make this middleware into a reusable function and apply it to just the routes you want to protect.